# How would I say "I'm going to be living here for a year"?

Tags: translation, preposition

Would 我要住这儿一年 be the most acceptable translation?

Comment: What's the context? Is "here" 1) an apartment or alike, 2) a region, 3) living here due to job assignment, or..?

Answer (score 4):

How would I say "I'm going to be living here for a year"?

You can say that 我 会 在 这里 住 一年. Other answers can be:

我 将会 在 这里 住 一年.

我 将要 在 这里 住 一年.

The best translation of "to be going to" is "将", "将要", "将会", "即将", etc.

Sometimes "将要" and "将会" can be shortened as "要" and "会". But please note that "要" and "会" would have much more meanings than just "将要" and "将会".

When translating the following two English sentences to Chinese, the results could be the same.

I'm going to live here for a year. (To do, simple present ) (我会在这里住一年).

I'm going to be living here for a year. (To be doing, present continuous) (我会在这里住一年).

If you have the intention to tell me that

"I'm going to be consistently living here for the whole year".

(Meaning you will not live anywhere else during this year)

then you can say:

我会一直在这里住一年. (一年之内我不会搬到别的地方去.)

这一年我一直住在这里.（哪儿都不会去，你可以随时来这里找我.）

Answer (score 3):

我要住这儿一年 is acceptable, but I consider 我要住**在**这儿一年, or 我要**在**这儿住一年 is more natural.

Answer (score 1):

The future being unpredictable, I like to couch predictions in terms of possibilities, not certainties.

How long do you intend to stay here?
你打算在这里呆多久？

I would like to stay for a year.
我想呆一年。

Comment: How do you choose between 呆 and 住?

Comment: @Stef: 住 only means staying in an apartment (or other types of dwelling or area of a localized nature). It does not mean living life in a region. If you do say something like 我要在中国住一年. First, that will raise spiritual eyeballs. Second, the best interpretation would be that your residence address will be in China, specifically. (住 could also mean station, the verb, and but meaning is only tangentially relevant here.) 呆, although colloquial, has the meaning of "stay" in general.